# Selecting rows from Pandas data frame to build bar chart

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot a barchart (matplotlib) from the following dataframe:
[image]

Vendors appear multiple times, with at most, one entry per year. (years range 2012-2020)

Given a vendor name (say "COLLEGE OF OPTOMETRISTS") - looking for a steer on how to form a histogram of x=year, y=Amount Paid  for the given vendor.

Any help greatly received.

DATA>> Json version of some data:

```
[{"Vendor Name":" (CMC Chester LTD) Trading as The N","year":2020,"Amount Paid":-37500.0},
{"Vendor Name":" COLLEGE OF OPTOMETRISTS","year":2013,"Amount Paid":-35300.0},
{"Vendor Name":" COLLEGE OF OPTOMETRISTS","year":2014,"Amount Paid":-36180.0},
{"Vendor Name":" COLLEGE OF OPTOMETRISTS","year":2015,"Amount Paid":-72360.0},
{"Vendor Name":" COLLEGE OF OPTOMETRISTS","year":2016,"Amount Paid":-36180.0},
{"Vendor Name":" COLLEGE OF OPTOMETRISTS","year":2017,"Amount Paid":-36180.0},
{"Vendor Name":" COLLEGE OF OPTOMETRISTS","year":2018,"Amount Paid":-36180.0},
{"Vendor Name":" COLLEGE OF OPTOMETRISTS","year":2019,"Amount Paid":-36180.0},
{"Vendor Name":" COOKE & ARKWRIGHT CLIENT AC","year":2012,"Amount Paid":-515693.4},
{"Vendor Name":" COOKE & ARKWRIGHT CLIENT AC","year":2013,"Amount Paid":-511219.2},
{"Vendor Name":" COOKE & ARKWRIGHT CLIENT AC","year":2014,"Amount Paid":-82072.2},
{"Vendor Name":" FFGF LTD","year":2019,"Amount Paid":-25698.57},
{"Vendor Name":" FFGF LTD","year":2020,"Amount Paid":-28900.35}]
```

Comment: So would you like to form a histogram for just one vendor at a time? Because creating a histogram is really really simple. Can you also post your data in a format that we can easily replicate? Thanks.

Comment: @sophods - I'm OK creating histograms -- its the "selecting the data that matches" on the "vendor name".  So for eg I only want to make a histogram for the "COLLEGE OF OPTOMETRISTS" ....  > will post more suitable data in a mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter those rows using a binary mask.

Assuming your dataframe it's named `df` and you're plotting it with the `hist` method:

```
df[df['Vendor Name'] == WHATEVERNAMEYOUWANT].hist()
```

Comment: that produces two histograms -- one for "year" and one for "amount"  -- looking for one histogram -- with xaxis=year, yaxis=amount  -- same data, just presented diffferently.

I know I'm missing the point somewhere.

Comment: Select the column you wanna keep after the row selection, try adding a `['year']` before the `.hist` call

Comment: If you wanna plot that amount on the other columns, you're not after an histogram, it's a bar chart. In that case, keep the row filter, use the `plot` method instead. Treat it as the matplotlib plot method until something goes wrong, it usually works out

Comment: OMG!!! and there you have it --- too much staring... yes, a bar chart.  DOH!!

Comment: Glad I could help. You should edit the question to avoid noobs falling on this question when looking for actual histograms.

Comment: for the purposes of completion:  

df[df['Vendor Name'] == "POLICE CRIME COMMISSIONER GWENT"].plot.bar('Year',"Amount Paid")    << worked a treat -- thank you